# How do I combine multiple attributes from different nodes of an AWS cli result?

Tags: jq

I have a JSON response from an AWS CLI command that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
        "ImageId": "ami-03ededff12e34e59e",
        "InstanceId": "i-01e625ed10dadda91",
        "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
        "LaunchTime": "2022-04-18T02:35:03+00:00",
        "Monitoring": {
            "State": "disabled"
        },
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Key": "Name",
                "Value": "Some Server"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How do I extract the Instance ID and the Tag Name so that it prints like this:

```
Instance ID: i-01e625ed10dadda91
Name: Some Server
```

So far I've tried

```
jq '.[] | "Instance ID: \(.InstanceId) 
Tag Name: \(.Tags[0].Value)"'
```

But it will break as soon as there are multiple tags or when the tag don't exist.

Comment: I'm only interested where Tag == Name. Please ignore when there are no Tags, or a non-Name tag is defined.

Comment: So if no Name tags are present, should `Tag Name:` be present as empty or should be removed

Comment: Either way works, whichever is simpler is my preference because it would be pointless for me to display it if it's absent anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join multiple tags together and produce as a single result, combine them together in a CSV format like below

```
jq --raw-output '.[] | 
  "Instance ID: \(.InstanceId)\nTag Name: \( .Tags | map(select(.Key == "Name").Value) |join(","))"'
```

Note the inclusion of `\n` character inside the interpolated string sequence which expands into the newline when printed in raw output mode.

[jqplay demo - 1](https://jqplay.org/s/V1WFuV9b8T)

If you want to skip printing the Name field, in case if its empty, you need to add a bit more logic

```
jq --raw-output '.[] | 
  "Instance ID: \(.InstanceId)" as $x | 
  ( .Tags | map(select(.Key == "Name") ) ) as $y | 
  if ( $y | length ) > 0 then 
    $x + "\nName: \( $y | map(.Value) | join(",") )" 
  else $x end'
```

[jqplay demo - 2](https://jqplay.org/s/hQ_TcVTJrG)

Comment: Can we limit the Tags only to those where Key == Name?

Comment: Wow, I knew it wasn't going to be that easy for a beginner like me. Thank you, that works! Gotta learn how to use those functions.

Comment: `from_entries` would fit far better there, wouldn't it? https://jqplay.org/s/k5x233J56B

Comment: @oguzismail that’s an option! True